# No stack allocation whole program compilation?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, stack, allocation

If you write an app that is:

- Single threaded
- Has no cycles in call graph
- Doesn't use alloca or [VLAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)

Can modern whole program optimizing compilers optimize away all stack allocation (e.g. GCC, MSVC, ICC)? It seems like in those circumstances it should be able to allocate all possible stack space statically. By 'whole program' I mean the compiler has access to /all/ source code (no possiblity of dlopen'ing things at runtime, etc.).

Comment: They can certainly statically analyse the program for maximum stack usage (compilers for embedded platforms routinely do this).  Whether or not they optimise away stack allocation, I don't know.

Comment: You only pay for stack allocations once (in terms of growing the stack) anyway under most circumstances - you're not really saving anything by allocating it up front; unless you're looking for hard real-time constraints, I guess.

Comment: @Mat: Depending on the platform, accessing locations hard-coded at compile-time could be faster than accessing relative to the stack-pointer.

Comment: @Mat: Also 'free' is relative. You're still spending instructions to move the stack pointer. Not significant for most applications but in can matter for some.

Comment: Why would you want to?  Generally stack allocation tends to be more efficient than static allocation; that's why we use it in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

If you can *guarantee* the conditions you stated, then yes: it would be possible to effectively have the stack be completely statically allocated. Each function would have a block of stack memory.

However, will actual compilers do it? No.

It gains absolutely nothing to do so. Indeed, it may gain less than nothing. Often times, much of the working stack is in the cache, so modifications to it are pretty cheap. If the stack were in static memory, then the only time any particular function's "stack" memory would be cached would be if you had recently called that function. Using a real stack, you're more likely to be working in the cache.

Furthermore, giving each function a block of stack memory can easily make your program's static memory usage much larger than it needs to be. The stack is a fixed-size construct; no matter how many functions you have, the stack takes up a certain size. If you have 100,000 functions, and each function takes up 64 bytes of space, then your static "stack" must take up ~6.4MB of space.

Why? You're never going to be using most of that memory at any one time. The program would run just fine in a 1MB or even 512KB stack; why take up 6x that memory for nothing?

So it is both not a performance optimization *and* can bloats your program's memory.

Comment: The static space required may be smaller and have a better chance of fitting in cache than you're thinking. Since the compiler knows the full call graph, if it knows function A is never on the stack at the same time function B is, they can use the same space. Since we necessarily can't have callbacks if we know the full call graph I think this would probably happen a lot.

Comment: @JosephGarvin: If you have a function that calls two functions in series, a stack-based approach *guarantees* that at least some part of the second call's stack will be in the cache. No such guarantees exist in your method. And yes, it might be smaller. Then again, it might not.

Comment: @JosephGarvin: Also, you seem to forget that the conditions you place on this code make a *lot* of code flat-out impossible. Virtual functions or *any* form of runtime polymorphic function call? Nope. Callbacks? Gone. These are the foundation of the vast majority of GUI systems that exist, let alone any number of libraries. So your application scope is significantly smaller. And then there's the fact that DLLs are built on function pointers; without them, you can't have shared libraries of any kind. So again, that's a smaller application scope.

Comment: @JosephGarvin: Why develop an optimization that may not even *optimize* in the situations that it would work in, when the vast majority of applications wouldn't even qualify for it?

Comment: Nicol: Because /my/ applications may qualify for it ;) But yes in general you are right. For most it wouldn't be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment that's too long to be a comment:

Note that while all stack allocations may be theoretically optimized away, more may be allocated than necessary. This is not what the OP was asking, but it could be interesting to consider. Finding the minimum-sized allocation required would be equivalent to solving the halting problem. Imagine a program structured as:

```
<do 'something'>
<call last thing which happens to require more
 stack space than everything else in 'something'>
```

You only need the additional stack space if `<do 'something'>` "halts".

You can also imagine other variations where optimizing becomes arbitrarily hard. For example, your program could simply evaluate a 3SAT expression with user input and do something depending on that -- but that 3SAT expression may or may not have any value that results in true.

Perhaps there is a more trivial case: The user may simply never enter input that requires more stack space for processing.

Comment: ah, but compilers are allowed to assume that all functions return, so this argument doesn't apply.  (Good thoughtx though)

Comment: Note that solving the halting problem *in general* is not feasable.  However, there are some classes of programs for which checking for halting is doable.  I'm pretty sure that programs without cycles in the call graph are one such class of programs.  Besides, I think OP did not request the minimal possible stack space, only a fixed upper bound.  In that case, the whole halting problem stuff is unnecessary.

Comment: OP doesn't ask for calculation of the _presise_ bound for stack usage. (this calculation is actually equivalent to halting problem) However,   _some_ upper bound can be efficiently calculated if there are no cycles in the call graph

Comment: @user396672 -- I just came to the same conclusion myself. My mistake. I'll fix the answer to be less "this is an answer" and more of a "comment too long to be a comment."

Comment: @Andre -- Turing machines classically have no subroutines defined as part of their structure, so the notion of "call graph" isn't defined. Additionally, languages like BrainF*** are just a relatively simple loop and Turing complete if without memory bounds.

Comment: @Kaganar: Indeed, nothing prevents any specific function call to include a `while(true){}` which would prevent halting.  My note about halting was just that halting may be determined for some programs, and that one could impose sufficient restrictions on the language to make it possible to solve the halting problem for all programs written according to those restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for a compiler to do this, but it would be such a specific optimization that it probably wouldn't.

If you had a program that was completely inlined, you would take care of the overhead of setting up stack frames for function calls.

However, if you wanted to also get rid of stack allocations for local variables, the compiler has to transform those local variables into global variables. No compiler I know of does that, and on some platforms it takes extra instructions to reference a global variable compared to a local variable (as the address must be loaded with two instructions rather than one). Plus, since referencing a stack variable is such a common operation, it's usually encoded into a smaller instruction.

Comment: That's interesting, on what platforms is accessing a global slower than accessing stack? Couldn't a compiler then implement 'globals' by making them the first thing pushed on the stack at the beginning of program execution before main() and then only need 1 instruction as normal?

Comment: @JosephGarvin on RISC platforms like PowerPC it's definitely slower, since you have two instructions. On CISC, it's definitely a bigger instruction to access a global variable than a register relative variable.

As for whether you could make that transformation in general, you could. But it's so custom that it's almost never worth it; the indirection provided by the stack pointer is way more useful than avoiding it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you add "doesn't use any external libraries" to your list, any calls to external functions will require stack setup because they would have been compiled expecting the calling code to pass its parameters in a particular way, most likely on the stack. Additionally such libraries would almost certainly have to adjust the stack themslves for their own locals.

Additionally, depending on your precise application, even if you know that the stack could be allocated statically, it may be very hard for the compiler to know that there aren't any callbacks into your code, etc, that would cause a need for stack allocation.

I just can't see a case where the compile would attempt this optimization because allocating stack space is trivially fast already (a couple register manipulations I believe)

Comment: By "no cycles in call graph" I meant period, including callbacks. I'll clarify the question to ensure that it's understood by whole program I mean the compiler has access to /all/ the code. Also, 'fast' is relative ;)